# How to do while() the "pythonic way"

Tags: python

I want to do this:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(ventegroupee)")
while row = cursor.fetchone():
    print(row)
```

I get this:

```
  File "<input>", line 1
    while row = cursor.fetchone():
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the "pythonic" way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to use `while` loop at all, because cursors are iterable:

```
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

From the "Connections and cursors" section of [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors):

> *connection* and *cursor* mostly implement the standard Python DB-API
>   described in PEP 249 — except when it comes to transaction handling.

From the mentioned [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#next):

> *Cursor.next()*
>
> Return the next row from the currently executing SQL statement using
>   the same semantics as *.fetchone()*
>
> *Cursor.__iter__()*
>
> Return self to make cursors compatible to the iteration protocol

Answer (score 3):

You could use [for](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) like:

```
for row in cursor:
  ...
```

[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) you coul find a good tutorial about for loop in python:
[image]